# Using Orocos-BFL in ROS

Tags: ros, orocos, catkin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've tried including BFL into catkin using both

find_package(BFL REQUIRED) and find_package(orocos_bfl) but ROS is unable to find them. I've even tried find_package(bfl REQUIRED) without success.

Any ideas? bfl, orocos-bfl are both installed on my system and I can roscd to bfl.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187284/using-orocos-bfl-in-ros/) by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 644 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had to do something like that for compiling with bfl:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(BFL REQUIRED bfl)
include_directories(${BFL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("BFL include dirs:" ${BFL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("BFL library dirs:" ${BFL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
link_directories(${BFL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Then don't forget the:

```
target_link_libraries(your_executable
  ${BFL_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-07-21**:
Hi there, it works, thank you very much. I have also edited the documentation to reflect usage for others.
http://wiki.ros.org/bfl

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2014-07-22**:
Great, can you accept the answer as correct then to close the thread?

**Comment by [zurish](https://answers.ros.org/users/20878/zurish/) on 2015-03-12**:
Hi guys, I don't know where to add above lines. To the CMakeLists.txt who uses orocos-bfl? Or to orocos-bfl's CMakeLists.txt? Thank you.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2015-04-22**:
Hi. You should add it to the CMakeLists.txt who uses orocos-bfl. Cheers